# ADB suddenly started failing, and now won't reset

Tags: android, adb

ADB started working and now I can't see the list of my devices in Android Studio. I tried doing it from the `Reset` button in Android Monitor but it gives me this error:

```
[2017-06-29 22:29:21 - adb] error: could not install *smartsocket* 
listener: Address already in use
[2017-06-29 22:29:21 - ddms] 
'/Users/parhamgoudarzi/Desktop/Files/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-
server' failed -- run manually if necessary
[2017-06-29 22:29:21 - adb] ADB server didn't ACK
[2017-06-29 22:29:21 - adb] * failed to start daemon *
[2017-06-29 22:29:21 - adb] error: cannot connect to daemon
[2017-06-29 22:29:43 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2017-06-29 22:29:43 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2017-06-29 22:29:44 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
[2017-06-29 22:29:45 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 3
```

What ca I do? Is running manually `adb kill-server`? I tried doing that but terminal says adb is not a command or sth like that although I'm doing it inside the platform-tools folder in the sdk.

Comment: Looks like you are on a Mac. Is that right?

Answer (score -1):

try:
cd Desktop/Files/sdk/platform-tools/

./adb kill-server